# Вывести количество покупателей по 2 группам: покупатели, которые совершили в день регистрации платежей на сумму >=50$ и <50$

Tags: sql, база-данных, join, count

есть 2таблицы  с данными:

```
buyers
buyer_ID    NVARCHAR    ид покупателя
REGISTRATION_DATE   DATE    дата регистрации

PAYMENTS        
buyer_ID    NVARCHAR    ид покупателя
TRANSACTION_ID  NVARCHAR    ид транзакции
PAY_DATE    DATE    дата платежа
TRANSACTION_AMOUNT  FLOAT   сумма платежа
```

нужно сделать таблицу вывода в таком формате:

```
group   #buyers
>=50$   7
<50$    4
```

пытался делать вот так, но что-то не то:

```
SELECT COUNT(buers.buyer_ID) as "<50" FROM (
    SELECT * FROM buyers
    LEFT JOIN payments ON buyers.buyer_id = payments.buyer_id
    where buyers.pay_date=payments.registration_date)
HAVING sum(transaction_amount)<50
union all
SELECT COUNT(buyers.buyer_ID) as ">=50" FROM (
    SELECT * FROM buyers
    LEFT JOIN payments ON buyers.buyer_id = payments.buyer_id
    where buyers.pay_date=payments.registration_date)
HAVING sum(transaction_amount)>=50
```

спасибо

Comment: fiddle создайте... и покажите для него требуемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить с помощью подзапроса в подзапросе:

```
select 
  pg.groupAmount,
  count(pg.buyer_id) as cnt
from (
  select
    ps.buyer_id,
    case when ps.sumAmount < 50 then 1 else 2 end as groupAmount
  from (
    select 
      p.buyer_id, 
      sum(p.transaction_amount) as sumAmount
    from 
      payments p 
    group by 
      p.buyer_id       
  ) as ps
) as pg
group by 
  pg.groupAmount
```